# SSRS 2012, can I refer/display specific item from tablix to be used in Title

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have result tablix with 10 rows, on of them have ID=10, and corresponding Totals =900, I want to display that Totals=<900> value as part of Title in my chart.

I see that if I refer to is as |Fields!Totals.Value| it takes first value from that column, which is not correct is there a way to solve this quiz.  I don't want to sort by: order by Totals desc too.
For now I see that I can make up extra column ValueX=900 for rows and then use this. Or produce single row and this for my title.

As far I learned there is no way to use concept of OUTPUT VARIABLE in ssrs.

Answer (score 1):

You can always take the last of the values in the dataset  (if you're sure of the order)

eg.

```
=Last(Fields!Totals.Value,"myDataSet")
```

Comment: thanks trubs, it's actually same like  Fields!Totals.Value,"myDataSet" which by default take First, I solved my issue with separate column in dataset